# Returning Error Enumeration with an Arbitrary Variable

Tags: vector, error-handling, rust

I have a function in Rust using `try!` that attempts to collect all files in a directory recursively and insert them into a vector. Because the function uses `try!` to check errors, the compiler seems to expect an `io::Result` return from the function, and doesn't let me include the vector because the `try!` macro only returns a result. I need the vector to be returned.

Code is as follows:

```
mod os{
    use std::io;
    use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};
    //use std::fs;
    use std::path::Path;
    // one possible implementation of walking a directory only visiting files
    pub fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &Fn(&DirEntry)) -> (io::Result<()>,Vec<String>) {
        let mut filevec: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
        if try!(fs::metadata(dir)).is_dir() {
            for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
                let entry = try!(entry);
                if try!(fs::metadata(entry.path())).is_dir() {
                    try!(visit_dirs(&entry.path(), cb));
                } else {
                    cb(&entry);
                }
            }
        }
        (Ok(()),filevec)

    }
fn push_path_to_vec(p:&DirEntry,v:Vec<String>){
    v.push(p.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string());
}}
```

Here is the error:

```
<std macros>:5:8: 6:42 error: mismatched types:
 expected `(core::result::Result<(), std::io::error::Error>, collections::vec::Vec<collections::string::String>)`
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected tuple,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
```

I wonder if there's any idiomatic way to do this that I've missed.

Comment: You probably want the following function: `pub fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &Fn(&DirEntry)) -> io::Result<Vec<String>>`. Notice how the `Vec<String>` is now contained in the result.

Comment: By the way, I think the title of your question is not completely accurate, since it is not about returning multiple values in a function, right?

Comment: Probably not. I'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `visit_dirs` is wrong. The function should return a `Result`, but right now it returns a tuple. Since `try!` only works for functions returning a `Result`, your code doesn't compile. You can change the return value of `visit_dirs` in order to fix it:

```
pub fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &Fn(&DirEntry)) -> io::Result<Vec<String>>
```

The new definition means that a `Vec<String>` will be stored in the `Result` upon success. With some minor tweaks, the code is accepted by the compiler (see below)

```
mod os{
    use std::io;
    use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};
    //use std::fs;
    use std::path::Path;
    // one possible implementation of walking a directory only visiting files
    pub fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &Fn(&DirEntry)) -> io::Result<Vec<String>> {
        let mut filevec: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
        if try!(fs::metadata(dir)).is_dir() {
            for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
                let entry = try!(entry);
                if try!(fs::metadata(entry.path())).is_dir() {
                    try!(visit_dirs(&entry.path(), cb));
                } else {
                    cb(&entry);
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(filevec)
    }
fn push_path_to_vec(p:&DirEntry,mut v:Vec<String>){
    v.push(p.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string());
}}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That makes sense. Your earlier comment helped me get there independently(well..somewhat independently), but the confirmation is good.

Comment: Happy to help. Are you following [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) to learn Rust?

Comment: Yes I am. Not totally done learning, but I am finding the language very compelling.